# use file variable as module parameter in verilog

Tags: file, variables, parameters, module, verilog

I was working on a network on chip (NOC) project that a problem showed up. In NOC there are a number of routers and all of them have similar specification. This specification is included in a `.txt` file and i must read the file and instantiate routers based on that specification.

problem is that `defparam` right hand side must be constant and i can't set any of the sub module parameters based on the `.txt` file.

here is the code, i read a variable from file but i can not assign it to sub module parameter.

```
integer fd, fh, router_delay;

initial
begin
  fd = $fopen("spec.txt", "r");
  if (fd == 0) begin
    $display("error reading file");
  end
  else begin
    fh = $fscanf(fd, "router_delay=%d\n", router_delay);
    $fclose(fd);
  end
end

defparam noc.router_delay = router_delay;
NOC noc();
```

I just want to simulate the code, synthesis in not important here. By the way, i don't want to have each router read that file once. I want to read specification file once.

Any idea of how to pass `router_delay` variable to `noc` submodule ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the value need to be in a file? Based on the code a run-time argument is more appropriate; see `$value$plusargs`. Most tools allow compile arguments, but the implementation is different between tools; Usually `-D` or `+define+`

Comment: @toolic `router_delay` in `NOC` module is just a parameter and is used in many ways such as array size or generate loop condition. There is nothing special about it.

Comment: @Greg fortunately and unfortunately the value must be in a file.

Comment: Please explain the reason of down vote. Definitely it can help me improve my questions. Without a brief explanation, i think that a down vote is just a sign of exclusive awareness.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the code to be synthesizable at all, you can use just normal variables instead of parameters. You can then just use `noc.router_delay = whatever` from any procedural block.

If you need to keep the delays as parameters, you could write some script that will parse the txt file and produce a Verilog file with all the necessary `defparam` statements with compile-time constant values.

Comment: @Proks Thanks for the answer. I can not use variables because variables can not be used as array size or generate loop condition. I'm going to write the script.